# Hook relaited to combinations in prestashop

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I hope you're having a great day.

In my module I need to do an action after choosing new combination in product page .
So how can I see when user clicks on new combination ? does it have a hook ?

Comment: This probably causes a new background request that updates the cart content, so I would look in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use hook `actionAjaxDieProductControllerdisplayAjaxRefreshBefore` within PHP or you can use

```
prestashop.on('updateProduct', (args) => {
    // do your code here
});
```

within javascript